# Unity Games: How to keep state between scenes (all things within)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm starting with Unity and I'm still a newbie.

I'm trying to make an "escape style" game like any of these:
http://www.androidauthority.com/best-escape-games-android-686215/

**The main problem I have is that when the user moves from one scene to another and comes back, the scenes loads from scratch. The objects that the user has collected, the mechanisms that have been activated or modificated... Everything goes back to the beginning.**

I've been looking at Google. I understand the concept of **DontDestroy**, but it does not help me because precisely many objects have been destroyed and that is the state that I want to keep.

I've tried doing something with **PlayerPrefsX**, but it seems complicated to keep such complex states in simple arrays.

Am I missing something? Should I keep everything in one scene?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a case where serializing data into a file to retain game state would be helpful. Have you reviewed [Unity's own tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/persistence-saving-and-loading-data) on saving/loading data?

Comment: Thank you. I have thought about it, but moving between scenes will be something that will happen very often. I think that so many read/write accesses would be slow and inefficient on android filesystems, wouldn't?

Comment: If reading/writing would be a problem, then you could instead have a game state manager object that persists between scenes, which keeps collections of custom data classes that describe the state of a scene. When you load a scene, loop through the appropriate collection of data and modify its contents to bring it back to a particular state. And when you leave a scene, save its state to the manager object.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can the object manager be a simple c# script with DontDestroy? Or you mean a GameObject with a script... I'm a rookie with Unity. What type should the object manager be? Is there any example of this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I imagined it to be a script attached to a GameObject, calling `DontDestroyOnLoad()` to persist it, and saving/loading data during scene changes - but I haven't implemented one myself as a proof of concept. (Also, you could consider making this manager class a singleton, so it's easier to access and can be automatically created if it doesn't exist already.)

Comment: OK. But what the process of saving is supposed to do? Could I do this by storing the information in variables? Or the game state manager should persist the information on the disk in some way? Thanks for your time. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It depends on how your scenes might be manipulated by the player. If objects only move due to scripted events (player pushes button, steps on panel, etc.), then you could store a series of flags indicating which events have occurred and update the scene accordingly when it loads. On the other hand, if the player can physically manipulate the objects (moving them freely around the room, knocking them over), then recording physical attributes of those objects (position, rotation, velocity, angular velocity) may be necessary. You'll probably want a list of a custom class to store all the changes.